# Custom Date Validation

Tags: javascript, regex, date

I got a form with an inputmask dd/mm/yyyy

I need to add a validation in case user imput is incomplete ex. 12/mm/yyyy

The regex needs to be digits, forward slash / or null.

Anyone can provide the correct regex?

```
function customDateCheck(el){
  if ( !el.val().match(/[0-9][/]|null/) ) {
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try with:

```
function customDateCheck(el) {
  return !el.val() || /^\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}$/.test(el.val());
}
```

Comment: This works thanks, will accept your answer in a few minutes.